# How do I get the last day of the selected month in jQuery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the last day of the `selected` month in jquery datepicker on `onSelect`

My current code is written below:

```
  var j = jQuery.noConflict();
  j('.epo-field-date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '1m',
    firstDay: 1,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst, dateob) {

      var chosen_month = j.datepicker._defaults.monthNames[inst.selectedMonth];
      var chosen_day = date_selected_parts[2];

      j('.chosen-month .month').text(chosen_month);


    }
  });
```

For example, When I click any day in the month of January, I should be able to return the value `31` or depending on the last day of the selected day of the month.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this).datepicker('getDate');` within the `onSelect` event to get the selected date as a JavaScript `Date`.

To get the last day of the month, you can actually advance the month by `1`, and set the day of the month to `0`.

For example, if you wanted the last day in December, JavaScript allows you to fetch the day before `January 1` by getting `January 0`.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j('.epo-field-date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: '1m',
  firstDay: 1,
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst, dateob) {

    var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var selectedMonth = selectedDate.getMonth();
    var selectedYear = selectedDate.getFullYear();

    var lastDate = new Date(selectedYear, selectedMonth + 1, 0);
    var lastDay = lastDate.getDate();

    //Do something with lastDay

  }
});
```

An example using today's date:

```js
var today = new Date();
var month = today.getMonth();
var year = today.getFullYear();

var lastDate = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
var lastDay = lastDate.getDate();

console.log("Last day of the month:", lastDate.toLocaleString());
console.log("Date as number:", lastDay);
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, You can get selected year, month and create new date to get last date as following code below.

Here sample code for your reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <h2>JavaScript new Date()</h2>

 <p id="demo"></p>

 <script>
 var date = new Date();
 var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
 var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = lastDay;
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```